# VS Code with Rust Analyzer - Toml Parser Error in version.workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, toml

In my workspace, I have multiple crates. I'd like to use common version like this, which is valid as far as I know:

```
[package]
name = "ultibi"
version.workspace = true
edition = "2021"
```

However, VS Code highlights the script and `.w` as Toml Parser error: `Expected "=", [ \t] or [A-Za-z0-9_\-] but "." found.`

I am not sure if that's got anything to do with rust analyzer, but disabling `BETTER Toml` didn't help. How can I hide/ignore this error?

Comment: Not sure what extension you have, but `bungcip.better-toml` does error on this, and disabling it does fix that for me. It's also deprecated, and suggests `tamasfe.even-better-toml`: https://github.com/bungcip/better-toml

Comment: @drewtato you are right. After uninstalling it and restarting - problem is gone. Happy to accept your answer if you wish to post it, otherwise I can do that and mention you :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the extension [Better TOML (`bungcip.better-toml`)](https://github.com/bungcip/better-toml), which has this deprecation notice at the top of its readme:

> This repository is archieved. I currently don't have time to maintain this project anymore. I recommended to use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tamasfe.even-better-toml for better alternative.

The suggestion, [Even Better Toml](https://github.com/tamasfe/taplo), supports the syntax correctly.